# Troubleshooting Assistance Over Heating Regulator Due to GPIO?

Tags: microcontroller

Great site.  Thank you for taking the time to help me with my issue.
I am pretty much intermediate to novice in electronics.  The more I review schematics and look at circuit boards, starting to recognize common components, so making progress!

Working on repairing an existing board that uses a C8051F387 (MPU?  Micro-controller) to do everything.  Reading through the 320+ page datasheet, this thing is pretty amazing to me, such a little package.

Anyway, when everything is connected as it should be, the 5V regulator on the board gets super hot and will eventually start to make the board smoke. The C8051F387 does not get hot and continues to operate 'normally' despite I suspect 2 or 3 of the gpio pins are internally shorted.

Using some tricks, amp meter, temporarily cutting traces, lowering input current (slows down heat), measuring load on the amp meter,  I tracked down the area that makes the regulator 'smoke'..
This clearly is not the intention of the design as the heated area on the board has changed color..  It just doesn't look right.  Something is wrong.  Also notice the resistor R1 looks like it got very hot too.

If I can figure out how to post some pics, will gladly do so.

Pins 23 (P1.3), 24 (P1.2), and maybe pin 22 (P1.4).  These pins/traces lead to edge connectors with what looks to be a 100Ohm 'pull up' resistor (R1, R2, R3) coming from +5, and a transient voltage diode going to ground which I assume protects against spikes on the edge connector.

When I cut the +5 going to the pull up resistors, the regulator no longer gets hot, the resistors no longer get hot.   The device that plugs in to the edge connector also does not work.  I have yet to get this (last) part working with +5 or without +5 on the pull up.

It was working at one time, so there should be +5 going to these resistors.

The C8051*  does not seem to care.  It keeps functioning, does not get warm.. 
I find it odd that it operates as normal and maybe those GPIO pins are just fine.
The other GPIOs on that port do not over heat but have different readings from the one's that cause the 'short-circuit'... Same 100Ohm resistors..

My questions are how can I confirm -
1) if the port 1 GPIOS 2,3,4 are internally shorted or still work?
2) if the other GPIOs on the same port are OK?

I guess I've seen some situations where GPIOs broken internally and the rest of the chip functions.. 
Need someone else's input beside my own.

Thank you.

Now for some pictures...

[image: showing cut traces and solder blob on R1 and C2]

This picture shows 2 traces I cut to stop the over heating on the regulator.
The blob of solder between R1 and C2 is there to patch over a previous cut, it is the +5 feed from the bottom side.  The via on top of C2 there...
R1 gets super hot.

Removing +5 from between C2 and R1 stops all over heating, even when the traces circled in blue are connected.

Restoring +5 leading to R1 and cutting the lower blue circled trace (R1's pin/trace) going to the microcontroller, the result is R2 and R3 get hot.
Cutting out R2 and R3 seemed to make R1 heat up faster.  It seemed to me they share in the heat/resistance sharing.

The vias on R3, R2 go to the two vias just below the lower blue circle.

Could it be D12, D13 are hosed?

Are these indeed pull up resistors?

Why are they being pulled up?

So many questions.

Here is another view, sort-of zoomed out.
[image]

Comment: A pull up resistor is meant to make a logical 1.  Is it safe to assume that these (2) pins are being used as a UART?

Comment: There is a short, but it won't be in the micro.  With the power off I would start checking resistance values with one lead at the junction of C2/R1 and go from there.  The caps will block DC and the diodes will block it from one direction.

Comment: I'm seeing what might be a fan connector and maybe a bus connector.   A pullups purpose is to keep a line high, unless it is driven low.   I'm not seeing the makings of a serial connection.  Either 2 lines off a mcu go to a header(for use with a TTL->whatever cable) or it goes to some version of a MAX232.

Comment: Great idea, with the power off look for shorts starting at C2/R1.  ..  The fan connector is actually a UART that goes to the RS232/TTL converter and is how this micro gets its commands on what to do.  Not a fan.

Comment: Large traces and big diodes for a serial connector.  Industrial control?  If I had to guess, either a diode or cap shorted, I don't see anything else there that could pass that much current.

Answer (score 0):

After more testing I have determined the GPIO pins are broken.